# Why can't I get Openfire to start?

Tags: linux, installation

I am having trouble getting Openfire to work.  I done the following:

> ```
> [root@jiaoyou logs]# which java
> /usr/bin/java
> ```

and I've run this command:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/java /opt/openfire/jre/bin/java
```

but when starting Openfire, it still says:

```
cannot run command `/opt/openfire/jre/bin/java': No such file or directory
```

It seems like a permission issue, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: what is the output of: ls -latr /opt/openfire/jre/bin/java

Comment: [root@jiaoyou logs]# ls -latr /opt/openfire/jre/bin/java 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 daemon daemon 47116 2009-05-01 17:11 /opt/openfire/jre/bin/java

Comment: Thanks!... I like Pauls answer... did you set the JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 5):

This was solved for me, in CentOS6 64bit, using the following commands:

```
cd /opt/openfire/jre/bin
cp java java.bak
rm java
ln -s /usr/bin/java java
service openfire start
```

Comment: You are awesome. This is exactly what fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a 64-bit machine, you should install zlib package for 32-bit architectures.

For Redhat/Centos, use:

yum install -y zlib.i686

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/java is just a shell script that runs the actual binary.  If you don't have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set correctly, it might not be able to locate the binary if invoked through a symlink like that.

Another thing to keep in mind is that some distros of Linux put /usr/bin/java in place even though you haven't installed the Sun JRE.  Don't bother trying to use the GNU version of Java, it's rubbish.  Do you know if the Sun JRE is installed or not?  What does "java -version" tell you?

Comment: What happens when you type "java -version" on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is using the right command to start openfire. I have found that "service openfire start" actually doesn't work.

I attempted the above mentioned method of removing the java executable from opt/openfire/jre/bin and all that did was force me into reconfiguring all of my current openfire settings. Thank god I made that java.bak file.

I believe the proper method to stop|start|restart is from /opt/openfire/bin and run ./openfire start or from anywhere "/opt/openfire/bin/openfire start"

At least that's what worked for me.